# pygames pygame.quit() not working on Mac M1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pygame

Although I am fairly new to python, I have some experience with programming as a whole. I was watching a Tech With Tim tutorial on a python visualizer and everything was going well until I attempted to quit the window! for some reason, pygame.quit() does not work, even if I put sys.exit() or pygame.display.quit() after/before it. if someone has experienced this before, some help would be greatly appreciated as this is a big roadblock.

```
import pygame
import random 

pygame.init()

class DrawInformation:
    BLACK = 0, 0, 0
    WHITE = 255, 255, 255
    GREEN = 0, 255, 0
    RED = 255, 0, 0
    GREY = 128, 128, 128
    BACKGROUND_COLOR = WHITE

    SIDE_PAD = 100
    TOP_PAD = 150

def __init__(self, width, height, lst):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height

    self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Sorting Algorithm Visualization")
    self.set_list(lst)

def set_list(self, lst):
    self.list = lst
    self.min_val = min(lst)
    self.max_val = max(lst)

    self.block_width = round((self.width - self.SIDE_PAD) / len(lst))
    self.block_height = round((self.height - self.TOP_PAD) / (self.max_val - self.min_val))
    self.start_x = self.SIDE_PAD // 2


def generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val):
    lst = []

    for _ in range(n):
        val = random.randint(min_val, max_val)
        lst.append(val)

    return lst


def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    n = 50
    min_val = 0
    max_val = 100

    lst = generate_starting_list(n, min_val, max_val)
    draw_info = DrawInformation(800, 600, lst)

    while run == True:
        clock.tick(60)

        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

     pygame.display.quit()
     pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event check is incorrect because you're comparing an `Event` object to `pygame.QUIT`, which is an `int`, so the comparison always fails and you'd never be able to quit the game.

You need to compare `event.type == pygame.QUIT` like so:

```
while run == True:
    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # changed from 'event' to 'event.type'
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```